# 5 dimensional hypercube and its links

Tags: lattice-orders

I have a question regarding hypercubes. Please help me answer this.

How many nodes does a d-dimensional hypercube have and what is its diameter? Draw a single node in this architecture for d = 5 and show all of its links.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube

Comment: Write down how many verticies, edges & faces etc... that there are in a square, then do it for a cube, see if you can spot any patterns & guess what the values are for a hypercube...

Comment: How does this relate to the tag "lattice-orders"? There other three tags which include the lattice word: "integer-lattices", "vector-lattices" and "lattices-in-lie-groups".

Answer (score 1):

2^d nodes with diameter, the major diagonal, of sqr d * length of edge.
As a kid I drew hypercubes.  Start with a point and move it.  Then move that line.  Move that square and get a perspective of a cube.  Now move that cube in yet another direction on the paper.  It helps to use a different color for each move.  Alas, I did not keep my work.  I quit at four.  As for five as you reqested, I'll let you continue to the fifth move.  Thus you'll see all the links of a node.  There are d.